# Approximate \cos(x^2) using Composite Trapezoidal method

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

Find an approximation to $$\int_2^3 \cos(x^2)dx$$ using the Composite Trapezoidal method with $r = 3$ and estimate the error.

Attempt: using the composite trapezoidal formula I calculated the approximation was equal to $$\frac 16 [\cos(4) + \cos(9) + \cos(16) + \cos(9) $$ which is approximately -0.5723. However when calculating the error I am not sure how to find the maximum of the second derivative, $ -4x^2\cos(x^2) - 2\sin(x^2) $ and I am stuck here. Have I gone about this correctly so far, and how do I find the error?

Comment: Why are you evaluating the integrand at $x=4$ when the integral is from $2$ to $3$?  Even though I don't know what the "composite trapezoidal method" is, that seems off.

Comment: That term is $f(a)$ and _a_ is 2, so plugging in 2 for x in _x^2_ gives $cos(4)$

Comment: To clarify, $\cos(16) = \cos(4^2)$ is what I'm talking about.  (As I mentioned, evaluating the integrand, not merely cosine, at $x=4$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your "Composite Trapezoidal method" is my [Trapezoidal rule,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) then you've made an error in applying the approximation.

With a uniform $$\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n} = \frac{3-2}{3} = \frac{1}{3},$$
the trapezoidal rule gives
$$\begin{align*}\int_2^3 \cos\left(x^2\right)\,dx &\approx \frac{1}{6}\Big(\cos\left(2^2\right) + 2\cos\left((7/3)^2\right) + 2\cos\left((8/3)^2\right) + \cos\left(3^2\right)\Big) \\ &\approx 0.187472628\end{align*}$$

---

The error, as you've mentioned, is related to the second derivative
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2} (\cos(x^2)) = \frac{d}{dx}(-2x\sin(x^2)) = -4x^2\cos(x^2) - 2\sin(x^2)$$
In particular, if we want to merely find an upper bound for the absolute value of the second derivative (which is what it sounds like you want), we can note

$$\left|-4x^2\cos(x^2) - 2\sin(x^2)\right| \leq 4x^2|\cos(x^2)| + 2|\sin(x^2)| \leq 4x^2 + 2 \leq 4(3^2)+2 = 38$$ (the actual maximum is $\approx 25.8$ at $x=3$)

Using our estimate, we then estimate the error as
$$\text{|Error|} \leq \frac{(b-a)^3}{12n^2}\cdot 38 = \frac{38}{108} \approx 0.351851852$$
(using the actual maximum of the second derivative updates this upper limit on the error to $0.239,$ and using the error formula on each subinterval could further refine the error estimate)

Comment: You could also use $|A\cos w+B\sin w|\le\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$ to get an upper bound of about 26.

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann That's much easier.  For whatever reason (possibly because both $A$ and $w$ depend on $x$) I had blinders on and didn't notice that inequality.  However, how do you get $26$ out of it?  I seem to get $\approx 36$

Comment: I used a wrong factor, mentally converted $4=2^2$ in $2\sqrt{4x^4+1}$ into a $2$. Then the resulting bound is not that much better, the angle can not be neglected.